# How can I make this clock working without refreshing website?

Tags: javascript, clock

I have problem with this clock. At first timer didn't show up so I used defer and it appeared but time is only changing when I refresh website.

I just want to make this timer change itself with the real world time not only when I refresh website.

```js
const hourEl = document.getElementById('hour')
const minEl = document.getElementById('minutes')
const secEl = document.getElementById('seconds')
const ampmEl = document.getElementById('ampm')

function clockUpdate() {
  let h = new Date().getHours()
  let m = new Date().getMinutes()
  let s = new Date().getSeconds()
  let ampm = 'AM'
  if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    ampm = 'PM';
  }
  hourEl.innerHTML = h;
  minEl.innerHTML = m;
  secEl.innerHTML = s;
}
clockUpdate();
```

```html
<span id="hour"></span>:<span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds">:/span> <span id="ampm"></span>
```

Comment: Look into `window.setInterval`. Also it’s generally best to post your code as code, instead of images.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: I made you a snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout(functionRef, delay)` for repeat a function after a number of milliseconds and put your function each seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside setInterval

```js
const hourEl = document.getElementById('hour')
const minEl = document.getElementById('minutes')
const secEl = document.getElementById('seconds')
const ampmEl = document.getElementById('ampm')

function clockUpdate() {
  let h = new Date().getHours()
  let m = new Date().getMinutes()
  let s = new Date().getSeconds()
  let ampm = 'AM'
  if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    ampm = 'PM';
  }
  hourEl.innerHTML = h;
  minEl.innerHTML = m;
  secEl.innerHTML = s;
}
const int = setInterval(clockUpdate, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="hour"></span>
<span id="minutes"></span>
<span id="seconds"></span>
<span id="ampm"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap in a setInterval -  here I use half a sec since setInterval is not super reliable

I also use textContent and pad the numbers.
You forgot the ampm too

```js
const hourEl = document.getElementById('hour')
const minEl = document.getElementById('minutes')
const secEl = document.getElementById('seconds')
const ampmEl = document.getElementById('ampm')

function clockUpdate() {
  let h = new Date().getHours()
  let m = new Date().getMinutes()
  let s = new Date().getSeconds()
  let ampm = 'AM'
  if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    ampm = 'PM';
  }
  hourEl.textContent = String(h).padStart(2,"0");
  minEl.textContent = String(m).padStart(2,"0");
  secEl.textContent = String(s).padStart(2,"0");
  ampmEl.textContent= ampm;
}
setInterval(clockUpdate,500);
```

```html
<span id="hour"></span>:<span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span>:<span id="ampm"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You call the clockUpdate() function only once. Consider moving it into a setInterval()-function that runs every second (or faster for better accuracy)... like so:

`setInterval(clockUpdate, 1000);`